# Maven repo for quickfix/j with the attached source files

Tags: maven, quickfix

Does anyone know if there is a repo for quickfix/j with the attached source files?

Comment: Something wrong with [central](http://search.maven.org/#search|ga|1|quickfix) ?

Comment: @khmarbaise I don't think so, I don't understand why the person who created the repo didn't add the source :(

Comment: First the creator of the repository don't add sources this is in the responsibily of the maintainers of the package which in this case of the above package added the sources.